Are there places in the Alps suitable for travel with an elderly person?
I want to travel to the Alps with an elderly relative for a few days. He can walk quite well but can no longer do steep slopes or long walks. Are there any holiday villages or towns with suitable trails?

please explain "suitable trails". Would a village where your relative can walk on the village streets to restaurants and such be ok, or do you want a "nature experience" to a scenic lookout or view? Also, is this at the height of summer or dead of winter, it makes a big difference

I think you are more likely to succeed if you yourself find some candidate villages and trails and then ask "is the ABC trail ok for an elderly person who can't do steep slopes or walk longer than an hour?" "how far is the DEF lookout in GHI village from the village square?" [perhaps with extra details like "in the snow" or "on a summer day".] These sorts of questions are facts we can answer. "What might work for me" is not.

@KateGregory This will be in August and we're looking for nature trails.

@KateGregory I agree, but I would also note that the answer to the question as asked is certainly "yes."  The real question is not whether such places exist but how to identify them generally and/or whether any specific place meets the asker's criteria.

There's plenty - have you tried sites like outdooractive.com? They list trails and you can filter e.g. for easy trails with less than 200m climb. These criteria give me 69 results in Kleinwalsertal and 48 results in Zillertal, and that's only the first two places that came to my mind. The alps are a huge area, I bet there's many, many more. Too many to list them all and therefore too many to answer the "are there" question in a useful way (and as mentioned in the first comment, we don't do recommendations).

@Sabine that comment seems like it could be expanded into a useful answer.

There are plenty such places, because in between the mountains, you find a lot of beautiful valleys that often have hiking/walking trails along the valley with minimal climbs or you can take a lift up to a mountain and have a nearly flat walk there. I have been on several vacations to the alps with my parents, who also don't do steep climbs and long hikes, and this was never much of an issue.
How to find the right spot can be tricky. Probably, you should start by checking which places are good to reach from your place or have some other interesting features and then search around - I'm a skijumping fan so looking for towns/villages with skijumping hills near was our way of deciding on a place :) .
Once you found a "candidate village", you can try hiking websites, e.g. outdooractive.com (not affiliated, but a frequent user) to find a suitable place. They list user-created trails and you can filter the results. For example, looking for trails rated "easy" and with less than 200m climb (which usually aren't steep), outdooractive.com gives 69 results in Kleinwalsertal and 48 results in Zillertal, but only 7 results in Stubaital, so picking one of the first two would probably make for an enjoyable vacation, the latter one seems not to be made for you. Note: These were the first three places to cross my mind, these are not recommendations, but only examples.
